# How to install hadoop for c++ in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I want to install hadoop in windows and use c++ programming language. Please help me, what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

If you want to install Hadoop over Windows, you need a software called Cygwin. Cygwin is a large collection of GNU and Open Source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.

Method 2:
Building Hadoop Core

For installation refer below link

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

Comment: Right at the beginning of the tutorial you linked there is this: _**Do not** attempt to run the installation from within Cygwin. Cygwin is neither required nor supported._

Comment: OK. what should I do after installing Cygwin? I asked this question here to have all installation steps. Installing "Cygwin" is the first step. please explain more. thanks.